# Create dynamic abstract-ified filled shapes according to the outline of each letter in android?

Tags: android, graphics

I want to dynamically generate shapes based on the letters outputted in my app. I'd like to output shapes that is each based on connecting the farthest n (with n as any integer larger than 1) points on the outline of each letter. Farthest in respect to the "center" of each shape. I'd like some general guidance on the following questions: Is there a way to find the center of a letter in android, how do we measure the distance from this center to the outline of the letter and lastly, how do we generate a custom shape that's based on it as the aforementioned rules??

Comment: Some context, details of what you've tried, and ideally some examples of what you're trying to achieve (even if drawn on paint!) would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Tom: This is my idea: I've drawn the partial outline around each letter using the dotted red lines, portions of the letter may itself be part of the entire outline, e.g. the curvature of the e serve to outline the letter:http://i.imgur.com/80ahYbv.png